# Numeric to numeric with a format

Tags: sas

I want to transform a value with a simple transformation table like this:

```
invalue eg2atptnum
  1 = 0
  2 = 2
  3 = 4
  4 = 6
  5 = 8
  6 = 24;
```

`input()` requires character for input.
Is there a more straightforward way than `atptnum=input(put(mod(egtptnum,10),best.),eg2atptnum.);` to avoid implicit type conversion?

Both `atptnum` and `egtptnum` are numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to avoid the warning, you can use `cats` which does it for you.  It's a bit silly, though, given it's basically the same amount of work as the `put`.

IE:

```
atptnum = input(cats(mod(egatptnum,10)),egatptnum.);
```

A few less characters but not really helpful in the long run (Except if you want to make use of SAS's automatically using the right conversion, but that seems unlikely here).

Otherwise there is no direct way to do what you want using a format/informat - you must either have character on the left side or character on the right side (or both), you cannot go numeric to numeric.  That's because this is more or less a cheat: SAS didn't create formats/informats with the purpose of using them this way, it's just a handy way of doing it to make use of the number to/from character conversions.

There are all sorts of ways of doing this that don't use format/informat if you prefer.  Hash table is about the same work to set up, and is about as fast (in some cases faster, in some not, limited by memory size).

```
data eg2atptnum;
  input egtptnum atptnum;
  datalines;
  1 0
  2 2
  3 4
  4 6
  5 8
  6 24
  ;;;;
run;

data _null_;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    if 0 then set eg2atptnum;
    declare hash eg2at(dataset:'eg2atptnum');
    eg2at.defineKey('egtptnum');
    eg2at.defineData('atptnum');
    eg2at.defineDone();
  end;
  egtptnum=4;
  eg2at.find();
  put atptnum=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the vvaluex and mod functions are doing here. An input/putn combination works with a value format.

```
proc format;
value eg2atptnum
  1 = 0
  2 = 2
  3 = 4
  4 = 6
  5 = 8
  6 = 24;

run;

data have;
do i=1 to 6;
j=input(putn(i, 'eg2atptnum'),8.);
output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Why is `putn` any better or different than `put` here?  Doesn't seem like specifying the type at runtime is particularly interesting.

Comment: @Joe It is different... just ran a test against 10m obs, and it's consistently about 4 times slower. Unless you have a lot of put statements, and a tonne of observations (or a lot of macro looping) it's not going to make much of a difference though.

Comment: @RobertPenridge I wasn't thinking about that kind of different but that's a good point.